# How to add a new highlighting rule to mode-xml.js in ace?

Tags: javascript, regex, token, ace-editor

I would like to add a new rule to mode-xml.js in ace. How do I do that? For example, I would like to make sure that all words which are called "android" or "tools" to be purple coloured. I know that I have to edit the theme for having it in purple colour, but how do I add a new rule to the mode-xml.js file so that these words are identifiable by the theme file?

So I need help in creating a new highlighting rule for the mode-xml.js file under ace-builds by ace. I would like if some explanation is provided.

Comment: Why isn't anyone answering my question?

Comment: Do you want the text to be purple regardless of the theme, or just purple in a specific theme (like the default "Chrome")?

Comment: @aaplmath I choose the former. You know how inside a theme that you can change the colour of strings using `.ace_comment`, like that I would like to create a class like `ace_comment` so that I can change the colour of it.

Comment: Would those words be tag names or part of the text contained within the tags? (<android> or <text>Android</text>)

Comment: @aaplmath Those would be the part of the text inside the tags, in the following example I want the capitalised text to be purple ( <tagName ANDROID:id ="value"></tagName> )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method will highlight all occurrences of "Android" or "tools" in an attribute name (like `<element Android:id="myValue"></element>`). It will automatically work for all themes.

1. - If you are modifying `mode-xml.js`, find the `attributes` array in `this.$rules` (a simple search for `attributes:` — with a colon — should pull it up). Then proceed to step 2.
   - If you are modifying `mode-html.js`, find the **second** array called `attributes` within `this.addRules()` (**not** `this.$rules`). Then proceed to step 2.
2. Copy the code below and add it to the top of the `attributes` array (of whichever file you are modifying, as found in step 1). I've added a comma since it's not the last element in the array:

   ```
   {
       token: "purple_text",
       regex: "Android|tools",
       caseInsensitive: true
   },
   ```

   This creates a rule which finds the words "Android" and "tools" (as specified by the RegEx in the `regex` field) and, regardless of their case (as denoted by `caseInsensitive: true`), assigns them the class `ace_purple_text` (assigned in `token`; feel free to change the class name). You can use this structure to create additional rules, too.
3. In your CSS file (the one linked to `index.html`), add a new rule for `.ace_purple_text`. I have an example below that highlights the text purple:

   ```
   .ace_purple_text {
       color: purple;
   }
   ```